# How to bind a mouse key to HoverTrack?

Tags: c#, controller, oxyplot

I essentially want to switch the right and left mouse buttons. I want to pan with the left, and see the series values with the right button. Binding the left button to pan works fine, but when I try to bind the right mouse button to see the data a problem comes up - if I click it once, the data doesn't disappear unless the cursor leaves the PlotView. It acts as if I'm holding it, while in reality I'm not. I've provided some basic code below:

```
var plotViewMain = new PlotView();
var controller = new PlotController();

controller.UnbindAll();
controller.BindMouseDown(OxyMouseButton.Left, OxyPlot.PlotCommands.PanAt);
controller.BindMouseDown(OxyMouseButton.Right, OxyPlot.PlotCommands.HoverTrack);
plotViewMain.Controller = controller;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PlotCommands.HoverTrack` would display the data as long as the mouse hover over the points or track. If you are looking to display the data points only when user clicks the Point or Track, you should probably use PlotCommands.Track

```
controller.BindMouseDown(OxyMouseButton.Right, OxyPlot.PlotCommands.Track);
```